# IOS 8 Launch Screen Image iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I've seen many similar questions in stack overflow and I've looked at the apple guidlines but the solutions didn't work for me. My problem is that my launch screen image for iPad IOS 8 (I don't have an iPhone 6 or 6+ to test with at the moment) isn't filling the screen or displaying in landscape if the ipad is in landscape mode.

I have portrait images of my launch image one at 750x1334 (background_-my_app_name@2x.png), the other at 1242x2208 (background_-my_app_name@3x.png). What I'm seeing is a square, portrait version of my launch image whether or not it's in portrait mode.

The launch screen uiimage has the aspect ratio constraints applied and the view mode is "Scale to Fill". I can stretch it down with "Aspect Fill" but it still leaves a white border to the right and bottom. Some people have suggested using "-Portrait~ipad" and "-Landscape~ipad" as part of the image name or just using iPhone portrait and landscape images in xcassets but this didn't fix things for me. When doing this I also had landscape versions of both launch image sizes.

What naming convention do I use for launch images for iPad and iPhone 6/6+, both portrait AND landscape? And how should I set it up?

Edit:

Removing "LaunchScreen" from "Launch Screen File", and using a 750x1334 (myimage-Portrait@2x.png), 1242x2208 (myimage-Portrait@3x.png) and 2208x1242 image (myimage-Landscape@3x.png) in xcassets now means the portait version fills the screen, but the landscape one is black.